# Using cross join to find all the pairs that has same value and record the pair count

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to find a best way to find all the pairs that has same value and record the pair count. Here is what the data looks like:

```
    batch_number        item_number    line_type    
      001                 AA001           -1
      001                 AA100           +1
      002                 BB001           -1
      002                 BB100           +1
      003                 AA001           +1
                          ....            ..
```

Here, the line_type +1 means the item is product and line_type -1 indicates the item is ingredient. But there is also situation that the item is both product and ingredient like "AA001". What I want to do is Cartesian join the ingredients and products.    If any rows are returned where the ingredient and product in that row are exactly the same item number, I will that batch. But the table as over 100 thousand records. Is there a efficient way to do this? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the data structure for tables involved?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is very simple try this trick

```
SELECT item_number 
FROM   yourtable 
GROUP  BY item_number 
HAVING Sum(line_type) = 0
```

or

```
SELECT item_number 
FROM   yourtable 
GROUP  BY item_number 
HAVING Sum(CASE WHEN line_type IN ( 1, -1 ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 2
```

Other option in `having` clause

```
HAVING Count(CASE WHEN line_type IN ( 1, -1 ) THEN 1 END) = 2  
HAVING Count(CASE WHEN line_type = 1 THEN 1 END) = 1  
   AND Count(CASE WHEN line_type = -1 THEN 1 END) = 1
```

This will give you the `item_number` which is both `ingredient` and `product`. Now you can put this in a `sub-query` and pull the batch info

**Update :** To find those pairs that count greater than 1

```
HAVING Sum(CASE WHEN line_type IN ( 1, -1 ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 3
```

Comment: thank you so much @VR46, I missed mention on thing, I actually need find those pairs that count greater than 1. if there any way I can do this?

Comment: thank you so much. but you mean line_type in (1, -1), right?